# SELECT Records Where Date > Date On Each Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am working in Microsoft SQL Server

I have a table like below for **Campaign Responses** :

```
Id       Name           CreateDate
001      Tom Cruise     2018-08-29
002      Tom Hanks      2018-09-02
003      Bill Nye       2018-06-25
004      Johnny Cash    2018-06-27
```

I also have a table like below for **General Activities**:

```
Id   PersonId  Name         ActivityDate
117  001       Tom Cruise   2018-08-30
118  001       Tom Cruise   2018-09-31
211  003       Bill Nye     2018-06-26
212  003       Bill Nye     2018-06-27
```

I want to create a query that COUNTS the number of activities each campaign member has had AFTER the CreateDate in the Campaign Responses table.

I have tried below, but this only gives me records where there have been Activities after the initial response. I would like to see ALL campaign members and activities after response, even if activities = 0.

```
SELECT
  a.Id, 
  a.Name,
  a.CreateDate,
  b.XCount as ActivitiesAfterResponse
FROM [Campaign Responses] as a
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    PersonId,
    ActivityDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(Id)) as XCount
  FROM [General Activities]
  GROUP BY PersonId, ActivityDate
) as b on a.Id = b.PersonId

WHERE b.ActivityDate > a.CreateDate
```

Ideal results would be:

```
 Id      Name           CreateDate   ActivitesAfterResponse
001      Tom Cruise     2018-08-29           2
002      Tom Hanks      2018-09-02           0
003      Bill Nye       2018-06-25           2   
004      Johnny Cash    2018-06-27           0
```

Comment: Seems like a poor table design. Don't store person names in the activities table, the personid is all you need there.

Comment: The name actually isnt in the activities table. Just put in there to more easily demonstrate what I was looking for. But thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your `where` criteria to the `join`. It's currently negating your `outer join` and not returning those players without records.  I've also simplified your query a bit -- no need for the subquery from what I can tell:

```
select r.id, r.name, r.createdate, count(a.id) ActivitesAfterResponse
from [Campaign Responses] r
   left join  [General Activities] a on r.id = a.PersonId 
                                    and a.activitydate > r.createdate 
group by r.id, r.name, r.createdate
```

Comment: This worked. Much appreciated! Quick complimentary question if I can ask it ... in the LEFT JOIN statement, can I add additional conditions after the and ... such as ... and a.activitydate > r.createdate and Subject LIKE '%xyz%'

Comment: @hansolo No problem, you're welcome.  You can definitely add additional `where` criteria to the `on` criteria of the `join`.  If you have any issues, just let us know!

Comment: Yes you can and this is the only way to add them, as everywhere else it will negate your `LEFT JOIN`...

Comment: @sgeddes So awesome. Thank you for answering my somewhat remedial question. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` instead of grouping on ***all*** columns when you don't have to:

```
SELECT #cr.*, ActivityCount
FROM #cr
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS ActivityCount
    FROM #ga
    WHERE #ga.PersonID = #cr.Id AND #ga.ActivityDate >= #cr.CreateDate
) AS ca
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your where clause to :

```
WHERE b.ActivityDate > a.CreateDate or b.ActivityDate is null
```